# Issues creating multidimensional array chess board in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I'm trying to create a basic chess board in C++ and output it.

I set up a multidimensional board array of characters as an initial test, and put characters in to represent each piece. This output odd results, so I stripped down the code to the following, which is intended to create a board with two rows of pawns and a rook in each corner, labelled a, b, c and d.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Game
{
    public:

    int turn;
    char player;
    char board[7][7];

    Game()
    {
        turn = 1;
        player = 'w';

        int x,y;
        for(y=0;y<=7;y++) for(x=0;x<=7;x++) board[x][y] = '.';
        board[0][0] = 'a';
        board[7][0] = 'b';
        board[0][7] = 'c';
        board[7][7] = 'd';
        for(x=0;x<=7;x++) board[x][1] = 'p';
        for(x=0;x<=7;x++) board[x][6] = 'p';

    }

    string getBoard()
    {
        string result = "";
        int x,y;
        for(y=0;y<=7;y++)
        {
            for(x=0;x<=7;x++) result += board[x][y];
            result += "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

I'm using the following to test:

```
Game game;
cout << game.getBoard();
```

and am getting the following result:

```
ac.....b
pppppppp
........
........
........
........
pppppppp
c.....bd
```

Any ideas why the rooks are duplicated and not just appearing in the corners? I can not seem to track down the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since a chess board has 8x8 size change your board declaration to:

```
char board[8][8];
```

Your current array is of size 7x7,

```
char board[7][7];
```

Since C++ arrays are 0-based 7 is not a valid index for both the dimensions. So you can't do:

```
for(x=0;x<=7;x++) board[x][1] = ...
```

or

```
board[0][7] = 'c';
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel rather stupid now. I've obviously been using PHP too much and forgot that the definition itself is not zero-based, which I why I put char board[7][7].

Answer (score 2):

The the legal subscripts for `char board[7][7]` are `0..6, 0..6`.

Answer (score 0):

agree, you should have declared char board[8][8] !!!!!
if i remember well, chessboards always have 64 squares.....